# Create a tag for generating @link in Play2.0

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0

while actively learning Play2.0 I am stuck with creating a tag. In the sample application, called computer-database, the following helper is created in the list template:

```
@****************************************
* Helper generating navigation links    *
****************************************@
@link(newPage:Int, newSortBy:String) = @{

var sortBy = currentSortBy
var order = currentOrder

if(newSortBy != null) {
    sortBy = newSortBy
    if(currentSortBy == newSortBy) {
        if(currentOrder == "asc") {
            order = "desc"
        } else {
            order = "asc"
        }
    } else {
        order = "asc"
    }
}

// Generate the link
controllers.orders.routes.Work.list(newPage, sortBy, order, currentFilter)

}
```

Since I want to use this helper in a view templates I thought that the best solution would be to create a tag for it. So I did the following (in my tags package):

```
@(newPage : Int, newSortBy:String) {
    var sortBy = currentSortBy
    var order = currentOrder

    if(newSortBy != null) {
        sortBy = newSortBy
        if(currentSortBy == newSortBy) {
            if(currentOrder == "asc") {
                order = "desc"
            } else {
                order = "asc"
            }
        } else {
            order = "asc"
        }
    }
    // Generate the link
    controllers.orders.routes.Computer.list(newPage, sortBy, order, currentFilter)
}
```

But, obviously this is not working and I do not know where or why it is not working.

Thanks for the input.

**UPDATE WITH ANSWER:**

So in Scala template we have to define, just as in Java, the arguments that are passed to this view (Note: that the variables that you will use in the javascript must be passed too!). The template will be compiled as a method as stated in [the documentation](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0/JavaTemplates).

The working tag looks like:

```
@(newPage : Int, newSortBy : String, currentSortBy: String, currentOrder: String, currentFilter : String ) @{
    var sortBy = currentSortBy
    var order = currentOrder

    if(newSortBy != null) {
        sortBy = newSortBy
        if(currentSortBy == newSortBy) {
            if(currentOrder == "asc") {
                order = "desc"
            } else {
                order = "asc"
            }
        } else {
            order = "asc"
        }
    }

    // Generate the link
    controllers.orders.routes.Work.list(newPage, sortBy, order, currentFilter)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick is that the first version uses a [template syntax](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0/ScalaTemplates) allowing to write Scala code instead of HTML: `@{ val scalaVal = 42}`.

In your tag, the template engine interpretes your code as HTML.

If you want to copy-paste this code, don’t forget the leading `@` before the opening brace.